# Python Pandas Get Values According to If/Else

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

My input dataframe;

```
Order    Need   WarehouseStock   StoreStock
1        3      74               5
0        4      44               44
0        0      44               44
6        12     44               44
0        6      644              44
6        6      44               44
```

I want to count whether any difference or not among "Order" and Need values with below code;

```
difference = df['Need'] - df['Order']
mask = difference.between(-1,1)                                                              
print (f'Count: {(~mask).sum()}')
```

I want to that something like this;

If (WarehouseStock-StoreStock) >= Need:

```
difference1 = df['Need'] - df['Order']
mask1 = difference1.between(-1,1)                                                              
print (f'Count: {(~mask1).sum()}')
```

Else

```
difference2 = df['Need'] - df['Order']
mask2 = difference2.between(-5,5)                                                              
print (f'Count: {(~mask2).sum()}')
```

Desired Outputs are;

Count 3

```
Order    Need   WarehouseStock   StoreStock
1        3      74               5
6        12     44               44
0        6      644              44
```

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `numpy.where` with `pandas.Series.between`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = df['Need'] - df['Order']
ind = np.where((df['WarehouseStock'] - df['StoreStock']).ge(df['Need']), ~s.between(-1, 1), ~s.between(-5 , 5))
```

Output:

```
ind.sum()
# 3

df[ind]
   Order  Need  WarehouseStock  StoreStock
0      1     3              74           5
3      6    12              44          44
4      0     6             644          44
```